# Dynamically binding URL with Image doesn't work as expected

Tags: knockout.js

Trying to dynamically bind the URL with a image.

```
<a class="dis-block how1-child1 trans-03" data-bind="attr: { href: latest()[1].url, title: latest()[1].title}, text: latest()[1].title">

     <img data-bind="attr:{src: latest()[1].imageData}">

</a>
```

Actual result : Only  tag content is displayed. Image is not getting appended, though imageData exists.

Expected result : Binding for  and  should work

Answer (score 1):

It should work. What is the exact content of imageData? A URL or base64?

**Edited:**
The binding text on the anchor tag has the effect of removing all child nodes.
If you want to add a text next to the image you could do this:

```
<a class="dis-block how1-child1 trans-03" data-bind="attr: { href: latest()[1].url, title: latest()[1].title}">
     <img data-bind="attr:{src: latest()[1].imageData}">
     <span data-bind="text: latest()[1].title"></span>
</a>
```

Make sure the base image starts with 'data:img/png;base64,' prefix, with the right mimetype according with your image type.

Comment: It's base64. Server will send the encoded base64 and UI will decrypt and assign to image. Tried printing image with out anchor tag, it worked.

Comment: In this case, imageData should start with 'data: img/png;base64,', where 'img/png' is the mimetype of your image. Is it so?

Comment: Ok, I've looked better: the binding text on the <a> tag has the effect of overriding the internal child nodes. Try removing the text binding ...

Comment: Thanks. The solution provided will not fit my design. I'll alter my design. I would like to know, overriding the child nodes is a KO issue.

Comment: No, isn't a KO issue. If you don't want a additional span inside your anchor, you can insert your text with the containerless syntax of KO like this: <!--ko text: latest()[1].title--><!--/ko--> (see https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html#note-3-using-text-without-a-container-element).